# C#: Use large icon for exe

Tags: c#, exe

I have a multi-format `.ico` that scales up to 256x256 and looks beautiful when viewed in Windows Explorer.

But when added as an application icon to a .Net Framework .exe then it's 32x32 max in the compiled exe.

Any way to get the multi-size in there?

Comment: Google "windows reset shell icon cache" to get ahead.

Comment: thanks that was actuall it! :-)